# Почему не выполняется одна из целей в makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

Есть небольшая библиотека на С, состоящая из трёх файлов:

- lib.h – код
- test.c – тесты
- debug.h – дополнительный код для тестов.

Я хочу написать Makefile для того чтобы:

- Выполнять компиляцию всех файлов по `make`. Они должны появляться в директории `out`. Создавать её не нужно, она всегда есть, содержит файл `.gitkeep` и сама добавлена в `.gitignore`.
- Запускать тесты по `make test` → `.out/test -v`.
- Вычищать результаты прошлых двух действий по `make clean` → `git clean -fdx out`.

Вот что пока получилось:

```
.PHONY: all test

out/lib: lib.h
    gcc -o out/lib lib.h

out/test: test.c lib.h debug.h
    gcc -o out/test test.c

all: out/lib out/test

test: out/test
    ./out/test -v

clean:
    git clean -fdx out
```

Проблема 1: команда `make` создаёт только `out/lib`. Однако `make test` работает за неё: сначала компилирует `out/test`, потом запускает.

UPD: починил тем, что поставил цель `all: ...` перед `out/lib` и `out/test`. Теперь собираются обе. Однако для `test: ...` это не требуется, вполне распознаётся цель, описанная раньше. Всё равно не понимаю логику.

Проблема 2: среда разработки (CLion с плагином для Makefile) подчёркивает красным реквизиты в целях `out/lib` и `out/test` с сообщением "Unresolved prerequisite" и предлагает сделать "Create Rule". Не понимаю, зачем файлы с диска объявлять как цели, я же не буду делать `make lib.c`.

Что я делаю не так? С make познакомился пару часов назад, не стесняйтесь объяснять самые базовые вещи.

Comment: без параметров make запускает самую первую цель. Но всегда можно написать имя цели  и он ее выполнит. А то что CLion подчеркивает -  а кто его знает. Не факт, что его разрабы знают синтаксис Makefile.
Кстати, make lib.c - там можно писать. Это валидная цель. Она по умолчанию сделает gcc -o lib lib.c

Comment: @KoVadim ага, это всё проясняет. Разрабы плагина для работы с Makefile наверное должны знать синтаксис Makefile, но они не очень-то объясняют предлагаемые замены.

Comment: самое главное, что нужно помнить о makefile - это таб. то есть, цели начинаются с первой позиции, а вот команды внутри них отделаются строго табом.

Comment: @KoVadim да, в коде у меня везде табы, хотя здесь редактор заменил их на пробелы.

Comment: просто к слову: стремление складывать результаты обработки в какой-то отдельный каталог — по моему скромному мнению, неконструктивно и бессмысленно. то, что таким образом поступают какие-нибудь ide, никаким образом не оправдывает их разработчиков. // clion, кстати, вам об этом (неконструктивности и бессмысленности) как бы слегка намекает.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin без этого осложняется `make clean`, т.к. просто `git clean -fdx` удаляет слишком много.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, `make clean` и `git clean` — это как бы совершенно разные команды. если у вас какие-то проблемы с их (совместным/попеременным/ещё каким-нибудь) использованием, то имеет смысл задать новый вопрос с подробным изложением этих проблем.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin разумеется, я знаю, что это разные и несвязанные команды. Просто мне видится удобным помещать временные файлы в специальное место для временных файлов и удалять их с помощью `git clean`. Если помещать их в корень, то придётся поимённо перечислять их для удаления или хотя бы использовать wildcard, что уже не настолько универсально. А `git clean` в корне, конечно же, недопустим — разработчик потеряет текущие изменения.

Comment: не в корень. а в тот каталог, где находится makefile, в котором описаны правила создания этих файлов. часто для наименования подобных целей используют слова, [содержащие слово `clean`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) — в таких целях (аргументами программе `rm`) перечисляют удаляемое именно перечислением/вайлдкардами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

первое, что вы делаете неправильно — пытаетесь использовать отдельный (от текущих исходников) каталог для «складывания» результатов обработки исходников. нормальная практика: создаём каталог, в него помещаем *makefile*, исходники, обрабатываем их (программой `make`), результат обработки сохраняем в этом же каталоге.

---

второе, что вы делаете неправильно, точнее, понимаете неправильно — это выбор «умолчальной» цели. т.е., той цели, которая будет выполняться, если программе *make* не указать явно никакой цели.

так вот выполняться при этом будет **первая** встреченная в первом встреченном (или явно указанном) *makefile-е* цель (порядок поиска *makefile-ов*, если явно не указано имя с помощью опции `-f`: `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, `Makefile`).

если вы хотите, чтобы по умолчанию выполнялась цель с названием, например, `первая_цель`, то поместите её **первой**. оговорка: в принципе, саму реализацию (и пререквизиты) цели можно оставить и где-нибудь «в глубине» файла, но тогда всё равно надо поместить в начало файла «заглушку»:

```
# это строка-заглушка, необходимая просто для обозначения того, что
# «первая_цель» — это «умолчальная» цель
первая_цель:

другая_цель: пререквизиты
  команды

первая_цель: её_пререквизиты
  команды_для_выполнения_этой_цели
```

---

ещё стоит упомянуть про [специальную переменную `.DEFAULT_GOAL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-_002eDEFAULT_005fGOAL-_0028define-default-goal_0029), с помощью которой можно переопределить «умолчальную» цель.

Comment: Не согласен с **_пытаетесь использовать отдельный каталог для «складывания» результатов обработки исходников_**.  при работе с проектом создание отдельных каталогов для файлов с исходным кодом, объектных файлов , библиотек . Достаточно распрастроненая практика.

Comment: Мне складывание всего в одну папку кажется бардаком. Сейчас мне нужно ещё добавить конфиг doxygen и shell-скрипт для сборки и публикации документации. Если и они будут лежать в корне, то в результате получится 10 лежащих рядом файлов, из них только три - код, остальные служебные.

Comment: Взять хотя бы https://github.com/torvalds/linux: Makefile в корне, код в субдиректориях.

Comment: *Достаточно распрастроненая практика.* — вероятно, в той области, которая вам больше знакома.

Comment: *Взять хотя бы github.com/torvalds/linux: Makefile в корне, код в субдиректориях.* — неверное утверждение. сделайте поиск файлов с именем `[Mm]akefile` и тому подобных (часто используют суффикс `.mk`) и убедитесь сами.

Comment: *код в субдиректориях* — кстати, это как раз вполне обычная практика, когда файлы, используемые в качестве пререквизитов целей, или в качестве аргументов программам, выполняющимся для реализации цели, находятся не в том каталоге, где makefile (и куда будут сложены результаты реализации целей), а в других каталогах (глубже или выше или «выше и глубже, но по другому пути»  в дереве).

Comment: во! скажу другими словами: обычная практика — это: каталог, в котором создаются файлы, являющиеся целями в makefile-е, содержит и сам makefile. т.е., (как правило) makefile — рядом с теми файлами, которые он «создаёт». а [вышележащие makefile-ы «вызывают» этот makefile рекурсивно](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html).